# Replacing substrings based on lists

Tags: pandas, replace

I am trying to replace substrings in a data frame by the lists "name" and "lemma". As long as I enter the lists manually, the code delivers the result in the dataframe m.

```
name=['Charge','charge','Prepaid']
lemma=['Hallo','hallo','Hi']

m=sdf.replace(regex= name, value =lemma)
```

As soon as I am reading in both lists from an excel file, my code is not replacing the substrings anymore. I need to use an excel file, since the lists are in one table that is very large.

```
sdf= pd.read_excel('training_data.xlsx')
synonyms= pd.read_excel('synonyms.xlsx')

lemma=synonyms['lemma'].tolist() 
name=synonyms['name'].tolist()

m=sdf.replace(regex= name, value =lemma)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**df.replace()**

Replace values given in to_replace with value.

Values of the DataFrame are replaced with other values dynamically. This differs from updating with .loc or .iloc, which require you to specify a location to update with some value.

**in short**, this method won't make change on the series level, only on values.

This may achieve what you want:

```
sdf.regex = synonyms.name
sdf.value = synonyms.lemma
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to replace 'Charge' with 'Hallo' and 'charge' with 'hallo' and 'Prepaid' with 'Hi' then you can use `repalce()` and pass the list of words to finds as the first argument and the list of words to replace with as the second keyword argument `value`.

Try this:

```
df=df.replace(name, value=lemma)
```

Example:

```
name=['Charge','charge','Prepaid']
lemma=['Hallo','hallo','Hi']

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', 'Charge', 'E333', 'B442'],
              ['Karen', 'V434', 'Prepaid', 'B442'],
              ['Jill', 'V434', 'E333', 'charge'],
              ['Hank', 'Charge', 'E333', 'B442']],
             columns=['Name', 'ID_First', 'ID_Second', 'ID_Third'])

df=df.replace(name, value=lemma)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name ID_First ID_Second ID_Third
0    Bob    Hallo      E333     B442
1  Karen     V434        Hi     B442
2   Jill     V434      E333    hallo
3   Hank    Hallo      E333     B442
```